# ¿ Como colocar el contenido Html a un botón después de dar clic en el nuevamente?

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap

Estoy cambiando el contenido de un botón al hacer clic, pero no encuentro la manera de volver a colocar el contenido inicial después de hacer clic en el nuevamente. Utilizo **toggle** para hacer algunas acciones pero a la hora de cambiar el contenido no he tenido suerte:

```js
  // JQuery 
  $('#showResponse').click(function(event) {
     $('#showSend').toggle();
     $('#showResponse').toggleClass("btn-danger", "btn-primary");
     $('#showResponse').html('Volver <i class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
  });
```

```html
 <!-- HTML -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

                    <div class="row ">
                        <div class="col-md-12 text-center m-b-15">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light w-md" id="showResponse">Responder <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light w-md resizeDiv" id="showSend">Enviar <i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Lo que pretendo es que al hacer clic en el nuevamente, vuelva a cargar el contenido inicial **(responder)**

Comment: amigo explicate mejor la ultima parte, que quieres que se muestre exactamente

Comment: al ejecutar el botón, esté inicialmente tiene un valor de **Responder**, al dar clic éste cambia de contenido y toma el valor de **Volver**  y así se queda hasta reiniciar el contenido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este caso comprobando la visibilidad de otro boton que ocultas y visualizas puede cambiar el texto.

```js
// JQuery 
  $('#showResponse').click(function(event) {
     $('#showSend').toggle(0, function(){
       if($(this).is(":visible"))
          $('#showResponse').html('Responder <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
       else
          $('#showResponse').html('Volver <i class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
       });
     $('#showResponse').toggleClass("btn-danger", "btn-primary");
    
  });
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

                    <div class="row ">
                        <div class="col-md-12 text-center m-b-15">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light w-md" id="showResponse">Responder <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light w-md resizeDiv" id="showSend">Enviar <i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Genial muchas gracias, aunque no me gusta la animación, voy a combinar las dos respuestas :)

Comment: Es solo configurar la duración en 0ms .toggle(0,... y con esto desaparece la animación.

Answer (score 3):

Solo agregale un `if` después que haces el `.toggle()`. Verificas que contenga la clase `btn-danger`. Te dejo el script

```js
// JQuery 
  $('#showResponse').click(function(event) {
     $('#showSend').toggle();
     $('#showResponse').toggleClass("btn-danger", "btn-primary");
    if($('#showResponse').hasClass("btn-danger")){
      $('#showResponse').html('Volver <i class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
     }else{
      $('#showResponse').html('Responder <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
     }
     
  });
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

                    <div class="row ">
                        <div class="col-md-12 text-center m-b-15">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light w-md" id="showResponse">Responder <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light w-md resizeDiv" id="showSend">Enviar <i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: No se me ocurría como hacerlo, Muchas gracias.

Comment: Perfecto, felicidades por tu código.